# How to change server 500 to 404 in response

Tags: java, api, rest, http

I have a service which return a object. when the object is null it returns 500  internal server error code . how can I change it to 404 object not found . I have a response object which is a class object and have certain attributes. Any help

Comment: without any further information, code snippets etc it's very hard to help you with your problem

Comment: provide code snippet..can't help

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
    //some code
} catch(Exception ex) {
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);// 404
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/404.htm").forward(request, response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All we can do at this point is guess at the issue. However

> when the object is null it returns 500 internal server

Makes it sound like you are getting a null pointer exception. You could:

- check if the returned object is null and if it is return a 404.
- `try/catch`
- Custom error handler that changes NPEs to 404s (don't do this, it is a horrid idea).
- Change the data layer to throw a "not found" exception and add a custom error handler for that.